# Adding custom tags to jar manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have a requirement wherein I wanted to put some user defined tags in jar manifest file. I was wondering if it is possible to do so?

- If yes, any example?
- if no. :( why not?

Comment: What "custom tags" are you talking about? JSP tags?

Comment: Are you referring to name:value pairs in the MANIFEST.MF file of a JAR?

Comment: Yes, custom name:value pairs in MANIFEST.MF file of a JAR

Answer (score 7):

> I was wondering if it is possible to do so?

Yes.

> If yes, any example?

```
silly-word: supercalafragilisticexpyaladocious
```

Custom enough for you?

See specifically the [JAR File Specification: Manifest Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest_Specification) for details on attributes and values.

> - manifest-file:                    main-section newline *individual-section
> - main-section:                    version-info newline *main-attribute
> - version-info:                      Manifest-Version : version-number
> - version-number :               digit+{.digit+}*
> - main-attribute:                 (any legitimate main attribute) newline
> - individual-section:             Name : value newline *perentry-attribute
> - perentry-attribute:            (any legitimate perentry attribute) newline
> - newline :                            CR LF | LF | CR (not followed by LF)
> - digit:                                {0-9}
>
> In the above specification, attributes that can appear in the main section are referred to as main attributes, whereas attributes that can appear in individual sections are referred to as per-entry attributes. Certain attributes can appear both in the main section and the individual sections, in which case the per-entry attribute value overrides the main attribute value for the specified entry. The two types of attributes are defined as follows. ..

Comment: +1 And a note. Attributes in the manifest file usually start with an uppercase letter, so it would be something like `Silly-word: supercalafragilisticexpyaladocious`

Comment: Is there any official spec on rules for placing custom attributes in manifest.mf?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel I could not find anything suggesting there were any specific constraints, though I imagine `:` might not be able to appear in the attribute name and characters like space would need to be encoded in the attribute..  I'd typically get Ant to create a manifest and hope it would handle the conversions and/or warn me of failure.  ;)

Comment: the spec doesn't tell what (any legitimate main attribute) might be - be opportunistic and use it for anything you like or be conservative and stick to just the specified names

Answer (score 1):

You can write pretty much whatever you want in your manifest file as long as you obey the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Manifest). So, what is your question really?

Comment: Non existing link.